# How to add one more properties in current class at runtime using C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have some properties in my viewmodel. At runtime I need to add one more property into that viewmodel.

For example:

```
var avm= new AnalysisViewModel();

foreach (var grades in gradeList)
{
  avm = new AnalysisViewModel
  {
     InfractionAverage = searchResult.Where(x=>x.GradeId == grades),
     //Here i want to add one move property and  want to assign value for my list.  
  };
}
```

Please guide me how to achieve this requirement

Comment: Why can't you add a property to `AnalysisViewModel`? What do you mean by "runtime"? And what does the Entity Framework has to do with this question?

Comment: There could be n number of property which will be decide at the running time.  name and number will be depend on the list's records which are getting from database using linq query.  ooh sorry that happen by mistaken  :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm try  with PropertyBuilder. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.propertybuilder.aspx